# Make Python requests library send Multipart POST as text/plain

Tags: python, python-requests

`requests` by default sends the text I pass it via the `files` parameter with a Content-Type `application/octet-stream` when sending multipart HTTP POST requests. Is there a way I can force it to be `text/plain` instead?

Comment: You mean you want each individual part in the multipart stream to have a mimetype of `text/plain`?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by `requests`, unfortunately. The underlying `urllib3` library does support handling of 3-value tuples (with filename, data and mime-type), but `requests` doesn't support any handling of the `files` parameter that allows for you to pass in the mime-type.

The way files for POST requests are being handled is currently [being reworked](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/935), but there is a [patch](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/803) that you could perhaps use for now.